# Treemap in Protovis

Tags: javascript, protovis

I liked the protovis library at http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis. I am trying to use it to create a treemap. Is there a way in Protovis' treemap layout by which we can indicate maximum level to show. Basically, I have a deep tree with depth 5 but I want to show nodes upto 3 levels only. If a user navigates into a node at level 3 then show its children, if any.

Any comments and help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: thank you for the link. This lib looks great.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) Is it possible to specify levels to show in the Treemap? and 2) How easy it is to customize this library?

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at Mike Bostock's new charting implementation.  Think about it as the next version of protovis and is called [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).  It is actively being developed and is in the process of porting most parts of protovis to it.  You can check the development groups in [google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/d3-js).  There is a simple program showing what you need to do in [bursting treemap](http://bl.ocks.org/916962).